# How to optimize the sql table containing the geography column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have stored geography data in "Location" table and based on this column we are searching nearest location for the given input. Below query is used to get the nearest locations within 25 miles and this query takes more than 4 seconds to retrieve 4000 records. We have even created spatial index on location field.

```
DECLARE @Distance INT

SET @Distance =25

DECLARE @h sys.GEOGRAPHY

SET @h =CONVERT(sys.GEOGRAPHY, 0xE6100000010C92B06F27119D4140111AC1C6F53554C0)

SELECT CenterLocationId,
       [Location].Stdistance(@h) * Cast(0.000621371 AS FLOAT(53)) AS Distance
FROM   [dbo].[CenterLocation]
WHERE  [Location].Stdistance(@h) * Cast(0.000621371 AS FLOAT(53)) <= @Distance
       AND IsDeleted = 0
ORDER  BY [Location].Stdistance(@h) * Cast(0.000621371 AS FLOAT(53))
```

Can anyone suggest how to improve this query performance in sql server 2014?

Comment: Try reindexing the table? see if this helps??

Comment: I'm not so fit with geographical data but it might help to do a preselection (e.g. as CTE) on all locations within a **square area** (simple maths...) of your distance and do the heavy calculation only for the points within this area?

Comment: Avoid using UDFs in queries. Of course you have to do it sometimes, but they increase execution time abnormally. So, you have spatial index on that column, that is ok. You need to get rid of functions like "cast" and that multiplier. My advice is to make column which will store that FLOAT. 
Also, if you always use Stdistance * 0.000621371, you may consider making PERSISTED column.

Answer (score 2):

Two things, not guaranteed to fix the issue, but can certainly help. They're both related:

```
SELECT CenterLocationId,
       [Location].Stdistance(@h) * Cast(0.000621371 AS FLOAT(53)) AS Distance
FROM   [dbo].[CenterLocation]
WHERE  [Location].Stdistance(@h) <= @Distance / Cast(0.000621371 AS FLOAT(53))
       AND IsDeleted = 0
ORDER  BY [Location].Stdistance(@h)
```

That is, prefer to not perform maths in the `WHERE` clause on expressions that depend on column values - you're forcing the server to perform that maths for each row and destroying any potential for using an index.

Also, similarly, it's pointless to perform a multiplication in the `ORDER BY` clause, since multiplication (by a positive number) doesn't change ordering.